# SpringBoot JPA - Not getting model class data member while fetching that model class

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am implementing simple JPA Use case of Social media app .
There are 2 classes User and Post mentioned below .
When I try to list the user of particular id I am not getting posts of that user in
returned User Object

**User classs
**

```
package com.practice.learnsb.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Past;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;


@Entity(name = "user_details")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
   @Size(min = 4 ,message = "Name should have min of 4 letters")
   @JsonProperty ("user_name")
   private String name;
   @Past
    private LocalDate dob;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
   private List<Post> posts;

    public User() {

    }


    public User(Integer id, String name, LocalDate dob) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.dob = dob;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public LocalDate getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
        this.dob = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public List<Post> getPosts() {
        return posts;
    }

    public void setPosts(List<Post> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", dateOfBirth=" + dob +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Post class
**

```
package com.practice.learnsb.model;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer id;

    private String description;

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Post(Integer id, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Post() {
    }
}
```

**Controller
**

```
@RestController
public class UserJPAController {


    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;


    @GetMapping(path = "/jpa/user")
    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        return userRepository.findAll();

    }

   @GetMapping(path = "/jpa/user/{id}")
    public EntityModel<User> getUserById(@PathVariable int id){
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(id);


       if(user.isEmpty()){
           throw new UserNotFoundException("id"+id);
       }

        EntityModel<User> temp = EntityModel.of(user.get());
        WebMvcLinkBuilder link = linkTo(methodOn(this.getClass()).getAllUsers());
        temp.add(link.withRel("all-users"));
        return temp;
    }
}
```

**UserJPARepository
**

```
package com.practice.learnsb.repository;

import com.practice.learnsb.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Integer> {
}
```

We have initialized some Users and Posts in data.sql

```
insert into user_details(id,name,dob)
values(1001,'temp',current_date()-1),
      (1002,'temp1',current_date()-3),
      (1003,'temp2',current_date()-5),
      (1004,'temp3',current_date()-7);


insert into post(id,description,user_id)
values(2001,'post1',1001),
      (2002,'post2',1001),
      (2003,'post3',1002),
      (2004,'post4',1002);
```

When I hit the url `http://localhost:8080/jpa/user/1001`
I get the below response

```
{
    "dob": "2023-03-11",
    "user_name": "temp",
    "_links": {
        "all-users": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/jpa/user"
        }
    }
}
```

So why are the posts for user not showing Up ?

Pls help me out !

Comment: Stop using classes annotated with `@Entity` in your API. Learn about proper 3tier architecture

Comment: Any suggestions Sir? I am new to this.

Comment: I don't see where you asked to return the post.

Comment: maybe add  a temo.add(user. getPosts()) before return temp

Comment: Remove FetchType.LAZY from your Posts class. It should work after that.

Answer (score 0):

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private List<Post> posts;
```

By default OneToMany relations are `FetchType.LAZY` that's why the post list is not fetching. The list will appear if you make it eager or write a custom repository function to get users with a posts list.

```java
@Query(value = "Select u from User u left join fetch u.posts where u.id = :id")
User getUserWithPostList(Integer id)
```

then replace the `userRepository.findById(id);` by `userRepository.getUserWithPostList(id);`